# Python CSV manipulation path

Tags: shell, filepath, export-to-csv

I work for a research lab and our programmer has left the company.  I been given the task to run one of his programs.  He left no documentation and I have no prior programming experience in Python.  He was the only one who knew how to use this program. The program is suppose to import a CSV file and do calculations.  I have no idea how to point the program to the specific file.  I need help figuring out where I need to place the CSV file path.  I have posted a sample of the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have been doing research for a few days now.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import json


category = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
catLog = {}
revLog = {}
nmvLog = {}
varvals = {}

def addRules(rules):
    geneRules = {}
    header = []
    with open(rules+'.csv') as toRules:
        rulesEr = csv.reader(toRules)
        for row in rulesEr:
            if row[0] == 'start':
                for column in row:
                    header.append(column.upper())
                    geneRules['header'] = header
            else:
                for x in range(1, len(row)-1):
                    if str(row[0]).strip() not in geneRules.keys():
                        geneRules[str(row[0]).strip()] = []
                    geneRules[str(row[0]).strip()].append(str(row[x]).strip())               
    print('Rules Loaded')
    return geneRules
```

Answer (score 0):

You execute `addRules` with full path to a csv file, without extenstion `.csv`.

For example, if file is `/tmp/subfolder/filename.csv` you run `addRules` as `addRules('/tmp/subfolder/filename')`